# Access Local Images in React Native Based on API Response

Tags: python, arrays, react-native, performance, expo

I've developed a recommendation system in Python that serves as an API for my React Native client. When a user posts an image, the API returns five image paths. These images are stored locally in a folder, each with an index as the filename (e.g., 1.jpg, 2.jpg). My goal is to access these folder images based on the path indices returned by the API.

I initially tried using `require` like this:

```
const imageUrl = require(`./images/${url}.jpg`);
```

However, this approach didn't work. Then, the other way I found is this:

```
images: [
  require('./assets/images/1.jpg/'),
  require('./assets/images/2.jpg/'),
  require('./assets/images/3.jpg/'),
  require('./assets/images/4.jpg/'),
  require('./assets/images/5.jpg/'),
  require('./assets/images/6.jpg/'),
  require('./assets/images/7.jpg/'),
  // ...and so on
]
```

But this approach is not practical for my project since I have thousands of images, and it's inefficient. Additionally, I'm not sure if I'll be able to access these images through their indices according to the path indices returned by the API.

Is there a more efficient way to load and access these local images in React Native based on the API's response?